# ApplicationInsights > loglevel coming from env variables

Tags: .net, appinsights

Can we use environment variables (or even key vault, api management, ...) for saving the log level? If so, how?
I can't seem to find it anywhere.

End goal is to be able to change it during runtime without redeploy or editing `appsettings.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are opened to use a different service, maybe [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview).

> Azure App Configuration provides a service to centrally manage
> application settings. Modern programs, especially programs running in
> a cloud, generally have many components that are distributed in
> nature. Spreading configuration settings across these components can
> lead to hard-to-troubleshoot errors during an application deployment.
> Use App Configuration to store all the settings for your application
> and secure their accesses in one place.
>
> App Configuration makes it easier to implement the following
> scenarios:
>
> - Centralized management and distribution of hierarchical configuration
>   data for different environments and geographies
> - **Dynamic configuration changes without the need to redeploy or restart an application**
> - Control feature availability in real-time

Comment: yes, i am opened to different services. I guess the question is, how to feed it to appInsights settings? are you suggesting adding app configuration as another configuration provider? or some other way?

Comment: Exactly, if you are using appsettings.json, then you could try out using Azure App Configuration, where you can move your configuration. Then you can change log level from Azure or try to expose it to a 3rd party application to adjust it on the fly.